# In CakePHP, whats the best Image Upload / Resizing component you've used?

Tags: php, image, cakephp, upload, gdlib

Im looking for somthing that can belong to many many models and, hopfully, has all the resizing functionality built in too.

Wondering if there's any good suggestions out there, I don't want to pick the wrong one.

Or is it just worth building my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a pretty sweet image upload component a few years ago for Cake 1. I don't have a clue where the code is these days, but my friend Koa did a write up on it a while back:

http://labs.iamkoa.net/2007/10/23/image-upload-component-cakephp/

http://labs.iamkoa.net/2007/11/06/multiple-image-uploads-into-single-mysql-table-cakephp/

Might be something you can hack. It handles uploads, resizing (resize, crop, resize then crop, max, mix) and if I remember correctly, it might even do filters (flipping, inverse, greyscale).

I also ported the code to Zend framework (and PEAR file naming) for my new content management framework. It's all contained and much better now (does all the things I mentioned above and is pretty well documented). You can [download that here](http://typeoneerror.com/files/code/image-uploader.zip) (check out the ImageManipulator class. I think the FileUploader class has a dependency on my String utils class which you could easily remove if you want to use that.

Otherwise, I say roll your own. The component architecture in Cake was confusing to me at first so it could be a good learning XP if you don't know it yet. If you do, you can just grab someones uploader and convert it into a component for your Cake application.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Media plugin by [@nperson](http://twitter.com/nperson) https://github.com/davidpersson/media/wiki

Answer (score 1):

https://thoughtwm.com/code/ for the image upload
&
http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/ for the image resizing

Answer (score 0):

How about for getting EXIF/Meta info of the image?